# Open new window on load only on certain pages

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

```
$(document).ready( ->
    window.open $('[data-auto-popup]').find('a').attr("href"), "popupWindow", "width=600, height=600"
)
```

This will open the window on all pages that I visit; but I only want this to pop up on the page that has the data attribute: `data-auto-popup`. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you only want it to open on click of the `[data-auto-popup]` element?

Comment: I want it to open on that page after a form has been submitted. So it will open without having to be clicked.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `->`? `$(document).ready()` wants a function as its argument after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the window to open on submission of a form as per your comment, add a listener for the submission of that form, handle the form however you require then open the window. E.g.

```
$('#my-form').on('submit', function() {
    // Any form handling code
    // Open the window
});
```